# GetSentry - Recognize a plugin that's not in the same folder as the Sentry egg

Tags: django, virtualenv, sentry

I've installed [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/master/docs/quickstart/index.rst) using the easyinstall process which keeps all of the Sentry code in an egg folder inside of the VirtualEnv's site-packages. Now I'd like to add in the webhooks plugin...but I need to make a slight change in the functionality.

Doing a pip install on the sentry-webhooks plugin puts the webhook's code in the site-packages as well. The only problem is that since I'm going to make changes, I need to keep the changes in our team's repository for replication.

Ideally the file structure would look like this:

```
sentry-venv/
    -bin/
    -lib/
    -my-repository/
        --sentry.conf.py
        --modified-sentry-webhooks/
```

Is this possible? If it is, how would I go about telling Sentry where to find it?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

David helped me answer my question over at the [google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/getsentry/4RdQouNDtTs/40hJUaQtAYAJ), but I'll share here too.

In order to get this to work you have to use a packaging system to run the plugin's setup.py from the desired directory.

So in my case I cloned the webhooks repo from github into the `my-repository` folder. Then from the webhooks repo I ran `pip install -e .` to install it.  After that you're free to modify and changes are reflected upon restarting the webserver (just like any other django code).